# ui-router - controller will load twice when calling $state.go in it

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

## code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ui State Demo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!--AngularJS v1.5.9-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>

    <!--angular-ui-router v0.2.15-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('uiDemo', ['ui.router']);
        app.config(function($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider.state('parent', {
                url: '/parent',
                controller: 'ParentController'
            }).state('childOne', {
                controller: 'ChildOneController',
                template: '<h1>Child One</h2>'
            }).state('childTwo', {
                controller: 'ChildTwoController',
                template: '<h1>Child Two</h2>'
            });
        });
        app.controller('ParentController', ['$state', function($state) {
            console.log('Parent Controller Start');
            if (Math.round(Math.random()) == 0) {
                $state.go('childOne');
            } else {
                $state.go('childTwo');
            }
        }]);
        app.controller('ChildOneController', function() {
            console.log('Child One');
        });
        app.controller('ChildTwoController', function() {
            console.log('Child Two');
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="uiDemo">
    <nav>
        <a ui-sref="parent">Parent</a>
    </nav>

    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
</html>
```

State `parent` has a url while `childOne` and `childTwo` have none. They share same url with `parent`.

When I click `Parent`, it will redirect to `ChildOneController` or `ChildTwoController` by random, but will also load `ParentController` twice.

It works fine if I put two different urls on both ChildControllers. But I want to keep the url same as parent after redirected to ChildControllers.

Can someone help? How to avoid this twice loading issue?

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to keep the url same as parent after redirected to
>   ChildControllers. From comment: So I wonder is there a way to avoid
>   duplicated contoller loading and keep the 'parent' state and
>   controller?

#### Option1

You can write for `parent` state `abstract:true` so this controller will be loaded once only when state changes from `parent.childOne` to `parent.childTwo`

For example:

```
state('parent', 
 {
   url: '/parent',
   abstract:true,
   templateUrl: 'parent.html',
   controller: 'ParentController'                            
 })
 .state('parent.childOne',{ url: '/childOne',   templateUrl: 'childOne.html'})
 .state('parent.childTwo',{ url: '/childTwo',  templateUrl: 'childTwo.html'})
```

#### Option 2

You can do some trick to avoid to call controller second time:

At beginning of controller call:

```
 if ($state.transition) return;   //hack   https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/64
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could make the parent not a 'state' and just have it as a page controller tied to your nav.

```
<nav ng-controller="ParentController">
  <a ng-click="vm.loadChildState()">Parent</a>
</nav>
```

Make a method called loadChildState() in the 'parent' controller, which then performs as it does now, using $state.go.

It should still function the same, and clicking on the link will load up the individual child states as you currently have it, without re-loading the Parent Controller.

Comment: Actually the 'parent' here is also a 'child' state of an upper level. How to solve this if I want to keep the 'parent' state here?

Comment: You could remove the controller declaration on the parent state and keep the code i put above. It should only load the ParentController once on page load.

Comment: Yes, that works for the uiDemo. But in real case, we use `<a ui-sref="module"></a>` to redirect to different modules. So I wonder is there a way to avoid duplicated contoller loading and keep the 'parent' state and controller?